# Calculating Dissimilarity between attributes

Tags: data-mining

I would like to figure out how to calculate the dissimilarity between attributes Jack and Jim. Given the attributes table shown below

Given the Relational table.
[image]

[image]

and the example calculations
[image]

I would like to understand how the dissimilarity is calculated for Jack and Jim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand how to approach the problem now.

$q$: number of attributes equal to 1 Jack and Jim.

$r$: number of attributes equal to 1 Jim.

$s$: number of attributes equal to 0 Jack, but equal to 1 Jim.

$t$: number of attributes equal to 0 for both Jack and Jim.

Therefore,

$d(\text{Jack},\text{Jim}) = {(r+s)\over(q+r+s)} = {(1+1)\over(1+1+1)} = 0.67$